# How to enable %postname% permalinks on Mac?

Tags: permalinks, apache, localhost

I'm using Mac OS X's built in Apache + PHP with MySQL. Everything works perfectly, except for my pretty %postname% permalinks — they just won't work. I have obviously enabled mod_rewrite and set the AllowOverride setting to All on my httpd.conf file. In case there's anything I can do (I really don't want to run MAMP), is there any programmatic way to use default permalinks on localhost using the very same template files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your /etc/users/{username}.conf should look like this:

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

You also have to change the name Apache runs under to be able to save the .htaccess rules and use the media uploader etc...

```
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>

User chris
Group admin #or you can use staff

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

The AllowOverride is listed a couple of times in httpd.conf make sure you changed the right one or both.  One is the default setting and the other is for Library/WebServer/Documents which you should change to whatever server document root your using.

Apache has to be restarted for any changes to take affect.  `sudo apachectl restart`

Also see [How to Install Apache and PHP on Mac OSX](http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/how-to-setup-apache-and-php-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! One question, though: where should I add that second <IfModule> code? Right after the first one, inside my .conf user file?

Comment: It should be already there towards the beginning of the file with the user and group set to _www. It's surrounded by comments that I removed to paste in here.

Answer (score 0):

there are two conf files for the built in apache, one for your username, which may be setting allowoverride to none.

Comment: Thanks, Milo. I just got to /etc/users/[username].conf and set AllowOverride to "All" as well. Let me reboot and see if it works already.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Any more suggestions?

Comment: do you have an .htaccess file with the proper rewrite rules?

Comment: Perfect, that's what was missing. Thanks, Milo! :)